# Xcode 4 - Changes in xib not reflecting on runtime

Tags: xcode, compilation

I have just upgraded to Xcode 4. When I am making any king of changes in an xib file this doesn't show on my simulator. I have even removed to xib from the project or quit Xcode - but still nothing - it runs as before.

It seems like the files are not compiled anymore.

Have you faced this kind of problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not sure if its compiling a file, just do a clean (default is command+K i think) and build again

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. What is strange is that although I have removed my xib file from the project, it runs ok. All other changes to my other xib files were reflected.

Comment: If you removed something from the project, make sure to clean and rebuild if you see strange behavior.  I have seen xcode not like to add or remove references to files in the compiled app file after they have been added/removed from the project.  That bug caused me many headaches on my last iphone game

Answer (score 3):

I faced this kind of problem after localizing my xib files (Xcode 4.3.3). Doing "Clean" and "Build" did not help. I had to remove the App from my iPad and from the simulator to get the new versions running.

Comment: I had the same case. It was fixed after removing the app from the device (or simulator) and re-installing again.